# Material-UI [v0.x] RaisedButton on hover styles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to change the styling of a Material-UI RaisedButton on hover, but it seems like there is no specific option to do that, as what happens on hover is sort of defined by material design guidelines.

Nevertheless, is there any way to change a button's styling (mainly color and background-color) when hovering over them?

I see m-ui is using a lot of different layers for their buttons, and currently adds a white transparent background on top of the button so that it performs well with all theme colours.

(To be more precise, I'd like to invert the colours between the colour and background-color.)

Comment: `RaisedButton` is deprecated, if you're using `Button` in the newer version, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64983425/9449426) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use CSS and some hackery, but below is a little component that wraps it up.

https://jsfiddle.net/0gjs8bh3/3/

```
const InvertHoverButton = ({ id, backgroundColor, labelColor }) => {
  // cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)
  const transition = `background-color 450ms ${MaterialUI.transitions.easeOutFunction} 0ms`;

    return (
    <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
        <style>
          {`
          #${id}:hover {
            transition: ${transition} !important;
            background-color: ${labelColor} !important;
            color: ${backgroundColor} !important;
          }

          #${id} {
            transition: ${transition} !important;
            background-color: ${backgroundColor} !important;
            color: ${labelColor} !important;
          }      
          `}
        </style>
        <RaisedButton id={id} backgroundColor={labelColor} labelColor={backgroundColor} className="test">Fiddle!</RaisedButton>
      </div>  
  );
};
```

Example:

```
// Must set id, backgroundColor and labelColor
<InvertHoverButton id="myButton" backgroundColor="red" labelColor="white">Fiddle!</InvertHoverButton>
```

You could choose to do the CSS differently here, but I am just trying to encapsulate it for you here on SO to make it more easily testable. If you choose to implement this differently, the key points are:

1) You need to use CSS `:hover` on the `<button>` element that RaisedButton renders

2) You must initialize the `RaisedButton`'s props with the colors inverted already (this is because material-ui uses the label color to determine hover overlay and ripple color). Use your CSS to 'fix' the swapped colors when not :hover'ing.

3) You need match the transition that material-ui uses on the button's label, or it won't animate correctly

NOTE: If you are using material-ui's custom theming, you could modify this component to use the raisedButton theme's primary/secondary colors rather than accepting custom colors.

Comment: Awesome. Though after 2 hours of trying to put this in my own setup, I am completely unable to replicate this properly. Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjs8bh3/4/

Do you know why using a className instead of an id doesn't work?

Also, what version of material-ui did you use for this fiddle? The HTML tree of the button on this fiddle and my own setup is not the same.

Comment: Not sure which version, I forked that jsFiddle from a basic one I found online. RE: id vs className... Looks like material-ui renders the id on the button element, but the className on its parent div. So, if you want to use className, you just have to tweak the CSS selectors a bit.  Update of your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96618s4b/1/

Comment: finally.. Instead of setting the button label between the 2 RaisedButton tags, I used the "label" prop of the component, in which case your approach has a color issue. Do you know how to make it work that way (it seems to be the canonical m-ui approach) ? fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjs8bh3/6/

Comment: Same techniques, but now you just have to style the text color on the span specifically: https://jsfiddle.net/0gjs8bh3/7/

Answer (score 34):

Sorry for a late answer, but maybe this will help someone else. Material-ui supports media queries like this (at least with 1.0):

```
const styles = {
  button: {
    padding: '10px',
    '&:hover': {
      background: 'blue'
    }
  },
  '@media (min-width: 1024px)': {
    button: {
      padding: '20px'
    }
  }
}
```

This example and more can be found from [Mark Dalgleish's post about unified styling language](https://medium.com/seek-blog/a-unified-styling-language-d0c208de2660).

Answer (score 4):

```js
 linkLabel:{
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#2bd5c6',
    '&:hover': {
      color: '#2bd5c6 !important',
    }
  }
```

sometimes 'hover' styles not applying even though you applied. U can achieve using '!important'.

```html
<a href="#" className={classes.linkLabel}> {'Link content'}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this, you can create `className` in reactjs, so you can do hover style..

```
import React from 'react';
import Style from 'style-it';

class Intro extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Style>
      {`
        .intro:hover {
          color: red;
        }
      `}
      <button className="intro">Save</button>
    </Style>
  }
}

export default Intro;
```