# how to write :hover and :focus in javascript css object

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to write styles for :hover and :focus inside react component. Here is what I have tried.

This is my component

```
<MyBtn className={classes.authBtn}> This is sample text </MyBtn>
```

In my styles object, I have tried these following some documents I have found on the web.

```
authBtn: {
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#1565C0'
        }
    }
```

Next,

```
'authBtn_hover': {
    backgroundColor: '#1565C0'
}
```

Next,

```
authBtn: {
            ':hover': {
                backgroundColor: '#1565C0'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css pseudo elements in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react). (The last answer states that it is impossible, and provides a component that will insert a `<style>` node in your own components.)

Comment: @Kaiido :after and :before can be written as inline in the next component. but when it comes to hover, active, focus it has to be written inside the component we are currently refering.

Comment: Oh and if it's MaterialUI, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46121511/3702797) states that it's possible with the `selector{'&:pseudo-class':{rule}}` syntax. Are you sure `authBtn` is a correct selector thought? Shouldn't it be `'.authBtn'`?

Comment: I was pointing you to the [4th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39383482/3702797), which is not only about pseudo-elements but also about pseudo-classes.

Comment: Here it is need to add the class name to the component as below.
`<MyBtn className={classes.authBtn}>`

I tried your suggestion like this. still no luck.

`authBtn: {
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the css styling. Rules I have tried overidden by the component inline css. so hover is also not worked. I have added important to the rule and it works correctly. here is the corrected code. Thank you for your support.

```
authBtn: {
    backgroundColor: '#1565C0',
    '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: '#0D47A1 !important',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem before, and I solved it using [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium)

This allows you to have styles defined as JS object, but it does support semi-states like hover. It comes with bunch of other helpful features

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium