# Material UI Button hover background color and text color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have created an `Appbar` component in React.js with 3 buttons in it but I would like to change the color when I hover over those buttons. The background color is `#3c52b2` and the text color is `#fff`. I would like the background color and text color exchange when I hover over the button.

I've tried the code below but still not working.

```js
Button: {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    boxShadow: 'none',
  },
  '&:active': {
    boxShadow: 'none',
    backgroundColor: '#3c52b2',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You probably don't want to change the button's `:active` state but the default and the `:hover` state. The following sets the button `color` to `#fff` and the `backgroundColor` to `#3c52b2` and switch them on `:hover`.

I'm not sure how you applied the updated styles (or how you tried to override the default styles), I created this snippet below with [`makeStyles()`](https://v3.material-ui.com/css-in-js/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook) but the idea is the same with the [`withStyles()` HOC](https://v3.material-ui.com/css-in-js/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component).

```js
const { 
  AppBar,
  Button,
  makeStyles,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} = MaterialUI

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  flexGrow: {
    flex: '1',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#3c52b2',
    color: '#fff',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      color: '#3c52b2',
  },
}})

function AppBarWithButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles()
  
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography>
          YourApp
        </Typography>
        <div className={classes.flexGrow} />
        <Button className={classes.button}>
          Button 1
        </Button>
        <Button className={classes.button}>
          Button 2
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppBarWithButtons />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

You could also just [create a new styled `button` component](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#shorthand):

```
const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#3c52b2',
    color: '#fff',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      color: '#3c52b2',
  },
}})(Button);
```

```js
const { 
  AppBar,
  Button,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  withStyles
} = MaterialUI

const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: '#3c52b2',
    color: '#fff',
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      color: '#3c52b2',
  },
}})(Button);

function AppBarWithButtons() {
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <Toolbar>
        <Typography>
          YourApp
        </Typography>
        <div style={{flex: '1'}} />
        <StyledButton>
          Button 1
        </StyledButton>
        <StyledButton>
          Button 2
        </StyledButton>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppBarWithButtons />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's still not working. Here is how I create my  button `<Button color="inherit">Home Page</Button>` , is the `color="inherit"` making the hover to loss its function? If so, how do I write it?

Comment: `color="inherit"` is no longer needed if you overwrite the styles. I've just updated my answer with snippets, it should help.

Comment: Okay, the `StyledButton` works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 30):

You can do that in **MUI v5** using [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content):

```
<Button
  variant="text"
  sx={{
    ':hover': {
      bgcolor: 'primary.main', // theme.palette.primary.main
      color: 'white',
    },
  }}
>
  Text
</Button>
```

Or [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) if you want to create a reusable component:

```
const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme, color = 'primary' }) => ({
  ':hover': {
    color: theme.palette[color].main,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
}));
```

```
<StyledButton variant="contained" color="primary">
  Contained
</StyledButton>
<StyledButton variant="contained" color="secondary">
  Contained
</StyledButton>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Hi! Greate answer. I tried your solution with `styled` but it worked only after I added `&:hover`. I'm using material-ui v4. I am not sure if this is the difference.

Comment: @C.Draghici `sx` and `styled` are only available in MUI v5 as mentioned in my answer. If you are using v4, you need to use `makeStyles`/`withStyles` as the alternatives. You can see the v4 docs [here](https://v4.mui.com/).

Comment: surprisingly on Material UI V5, `:hover` works and not `&:hover`. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want behaviour like default mui button - getting darker during hover, try this for mui theme:

```
import { darken } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

containedPrimary: {
    backgroundColor: someColor,
    '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: darken(someColor, 0.3),
    },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

easiest way I used in my application.

```
const useStyle = {
  Button: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#ffffff !important",
      boxShadow: "none !important",
    },
    "&:active": {
      boxShadow: "none !important",
      backgroundColor: "#3c52b2 !important",
    },
  },
};

return <Button sx={useStyle.button}>Click here</Button>;
```