# Changing mui controls to/from edit and view mode when clicked and lost focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

By default MUI date time picker gets rendered like this:

```
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
    <DatePicker
      views={["month", "year"]}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      label="Month & year"
      onChange={() => {}}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

[image]

I want it to look like normal label when it loses focus (say to emulate "View mode"):

[image]

And when one clicks on it, it should look like what is shown in first image (say to emulate "edit mode").

How we can achieve this?

PS1: here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-minsky-76urhs?file=/src/App.js)

PS2: can someone let me know where we can find mui lab on unpkg? I was not able to find it here. Wanted to embed the whole code here itself as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64983572/1317018) answer.